# How to apply window spec, but on 2 different columns (PySpark)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am facing a problem where the solution is not obvious to me from the API, and I am wondering what is the most efficient way to do that.

**The use case:**

I have collected tweets of two types and stored them in a dataframe (let's call them **Type1**, **Type2**). For this question, what matters is the *TimeStamp* it was posted. For each tweet of ***Type1***, I need to get all tweets of ***Type2***, that fall in a certain +/-***time-window*** around Type1's TimeStamp, and calculate a measure that depends on the time-delta within this time-window for each **Type2** tweet.

A simple **WindowSpec** on the TimeStamp column, according to what I've tried, can't work here. If I do that, I get a windowSpec for each timestamp, but I need only certain time stamps (Type1s). I tried to create two TimeStamp columns for each Type of tweets and sort by the Type1 Timestamps.. But the "rangesBetween" option seems to work only on the column that I sort by (I need to sort Type1-Timestamp column, but rangeBetween Type2-Timestamp column).

A solution that I came up with is to create 2 dataframes, one for each type. Then, for the **Type1** tweets, I *collect* into a list all the timestamps, and for each **Type2** tweet, I calculate a time-delta for every timestamp in this list and use it. This works, but the solution seems to me inefficient, and for large enough dataframe, the collection process may fail for memory issues anyway.

Hope I was clear enough with the problem description :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These would be possibly overlapping windows so not possible with a `partitionBy` and frames can't be "dynamic" (they can't be based on the current row's timestamp value).

It seems to me that you should be streaming the Twitter API using `Kafka` and doing operations on batches. But since you already have your dataframe let's try anyways.

Collecting values is not the right solution (it brings everything on the driver's memory). The other possibility is to do a cartesian join which is very costly and you'll end up filtering a lot of lines in the final operation. We can break down the problem by creating our own dynamic batches instead.

First let's create two sample dataframes for type tweets 1 and 2:

```py
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
time_deltas1 = np.random.randint(0, 10, 5).cumsum()
time_deltas2 = np.random.randint(0, 10, 20).cumsum()

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(
    sc.parallelize(zip(
        [dt.datetime(2017,1,1,0,0,0) + dt.timedelta(minutes=4*int(x)) for x in time_deltas1], 
        [chr(c) for c in range(ord('a'), ord('f'))]
    )), 
    ["ts1", "text1"]
)

df2 = spark.createDataFrame(
    sc.parallelize(zip(
        [dt.datetime(2017,1,1,0,0,0) + dt.timedelta(minutes=int(x)) + dt.timedelta(seconds = 30) for x in time_deltas2],
        [chr(c) for c in range(ord('f'), ord('z'))]
    )), 
    ["ts2", "text2"]
)

    +-------------------+-----+
    |                ts1|text1|
    +-------------------+-----+
    |2017-01-01 00:20:00|    a|
    |2017-01-01 00:20:00|    b|
    |2017-01-01 00:32:00|    c|
    |2017-01-01 00:44:00|    d|
    |2017-01-01 01:12:00|    e|
    +-------------------+-----+

    +-------------------+-----+
    |                ts2|text2|
    +-------------------+-----+
    |2017-01-01 00:09:30|    f|
    |2017-01-01 00:12:30|    g|
    |2017-01-01 00:17:30|    h|
    |2017-01-01 00:19:30|    i|
    |2017-01-01 00:23:30|    j|
    |2017-01-01 00:30:30|    k|
    |2017-01-01 00:36:30|    l|
    |2017-01-01 00:44:30|    m|
    |2017-01-01 00:52:30|    n|
    |2017-01-01 00:53:30|    o|
    |2017-01-01 00:59:30|    p|
    |2017-01-01 01:06:30|    q|
    |2017-01-01 01:13:30|    r|
    |2017-01-01 01:21:30|    s|
    |2017-01-01 01:22:30|    t|
    |2017-01-01 01:27:30|    u|
    |2017-01-01 01:36:30|    v|
    |2017-01-01 01:44:30|    w|
    |2017-01-01 01:53:30|    x|
    |2017-01-01 01:57:30|    y|
    +-------------------+-----+
```

Let's say our window should be +/- `n` minutes, thus we want a `2*n` minute window.

First we'll cast our `timestamps` as `int` and then we'll round them to the two nearest `2*n` minute timestamps:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf

n = 5*60   # for +/- 5 minutes  
df1 = df1.withColumn("ts1", psf.unix_timestamp(df1.ts1)).withColumn(
    "time_range", 
    psf.explode(psf.array((psf.col("ts1")/(2*n)).cast("int") * (2*n), ((1 + psf.col("ts1")/(2*n)).cast("int")) * (2*n)))
)

df2 = df2.withColumn("ts2", psf.unix_timestamp(df2.ts2)).withColumn(
    "time_range", 
    psf.explode(psf.array((psf.col("ts2")/(2*n)).cast("int") * (2*n), ((1 + psf.col("ts2")/(2*n)).cast("int")) * (2*n)))
)
```

*Converting the unix timestamp to timestamps to visualize:*

```py
    +-------------------+-----+-------------------+
    |                ts1|text1|         time_range|
    +-------------------+-----+-------------------+
    |2017-01-01 00:20:00|    a|2017-01-01 00:20:00|
    |2017-01-01 00:20:00|    a|2017-01-01 00:30:00|
    |2017-01-01 00:20:00|    b|2017-01-01 00:20:00|
    |2017-01-01 00:20:00|    b|2017-01-01 00:30:00|
    |2017-01-01 00:32:00|    c|2017-01-01 00:30:00|
    |2017-01-01 00:32:00|    c|2017-01-01 00:40:00|
    |2017-01-01 00:44:00|    d|2017-01-01 00:40:00|
    |2017-01-01 00:44:00|    d|2017-01-01 00:50:00|
    |2017-01-01 01:12:00|    e|2017-01-01 01:10:00|
    |2017-01-01 01:12:00|    e|2017-01-01 01:20:00|
    +-------------------+-----+-------------------+

    +-------------------+-----+-------------------+
    |                ts2|text2|         time_range|
    +-------------------+-----+-------------------+
    |2017-01-01 00:09:30|    f|2017-01-01 00:00:00|
    |2017-01-01 00:09:30|    f|2017-01-01 00:10:00|
    |2017-01-01 00:12:30|    g|2017-01-01 00:10:00|
    |2017-01-01 00:12:30|    g|2017-01-01 00:20:00|
    |2017-01-01 00:17:30|    h|2017-01-01 00:10:00|
    |2017-01-01 00:17:30|    h|2017-01-01 00:20:00|
    |2017-01-01 00:19:30|    i|2017-01-01 00:10:00|
    |2017-01-01 00:19:30|    i|2017-01-01 00:20:00|
    |2017-01-01 00:23:30|    j|2017-01-01 00:20:00|
    |2017-01-01 00:23:30|    j|2017-01-01 00:30:00|
    |2017-01-01 00:30:30|    k|2017-01-01 00:30:00|
    |2017-01-01 00:30:30|    k|2017-01-01 00:40:00|
    |2017-01-01 00:36:30|    l|2017-01-01 00:30:00|
    |2017-01-01 00:36:30|    l|2017-01-01 00:40:00|
    |2017-01-01 00:44:30|    m|2017-01-01 00:40:00|
    |2017-01-01 00:44:30|    m|2017-01-01 00:50:00|
    |2017-01-01 00:52:30|    n|2017-01-01 00:50:00|
    |2017-01-01 00:52:30|    n|2017-01-01 01:00:00|
    |2017-01-01 00:53:30|    o|2017-01-01 00:50:00|
    |2017-01-01 00:53:30|    o|2017-01-01 01:00:00|
    |2017-01-01 00:59:30|    p|2017-01-01 00:50:00|
    |2017-01-01 00:59:30|    p|2017-01-01 01:00:00|
    |2017-01-01 01:06:30|    q|2017-01-01 01:00:00|
    |2017-01-01 01:06:30|    q|2017-01-01 01:10:00|
    |2017-01-01 01:13:30|    r|2017-01-01 01:10:00|
    |2017-01-01 01:13:30|    r|2017-01-01 01:20:00|
    |2017-01-01 01:21:30|    s|2017-01-01 01:20:00|
    |2017-01-01 01:21:30|    s|2017-01-01 01:30:00|
    |2017-01-01 01:22:30|    t|2017-01-01 01:20:00|
    |2017-01-01 01:22:30|    t|2017-01-01 01:30:00|
    |2017-01-01 01:27:30|    u|2017-01-01 01:20:00|
    |2017-01-01 01:27:30|    u|2017-01-01 01:30:00|
    |2017-01-01 01:36:30|    v|2017-01-01 01:30:00|
    |2017-01-01 01:36:30|    v|2017-01-01 01:40:00|
    |2017-01-01 01:44:30|    w|2017-01-01 01:40:00|
    |2017-01-01 01:44:30|    w|2017-01-01 01:50:00|
    |2017-01-01 01:53:30|    x|2017-01-01 01:50:00|
    |2017-01-01 01:53:30|    x|2017-01-01 02:00:00|
    |2017-01-01 01:57:30|    y|2017-01-01 01:50:00|
    |2017-01-01 01:57:30|    y|2017-01-01 02:00:00|
    +-------------------+-----+-------------------+
```

We can now join the 2 dataframes, the final table will be smaller than a cartesian joined table, and filter on `|ts1 - ts2| <= n min`:

```py
df = df1.join(df2, "time_range").filter(
    (psf.abs(df1.ts1 - df2.ts2) <= n) | (psf.isnull(df2.ts2))
).withColumn("ts1", psf.from_unixtime("ts1")).withColumn("ts2", psf.from_unixtime("ts2"))
```

After converting the timestamp back to timestamp format we can collect distinct tweets of type 2:

```py
df = df.groupBy("ts1", "text1").agg(
    psf.collect_set(psf.struct("ts2", "text2")).alias("tweet2")
)

    +-------------------+-----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |ts1                |text1|tweet2                                                                     |
    +-------------------+-----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |2017-01-01 00:20:00|a    |[[2017-01-01 00:17:30,h], [2017-01-01 00:23:30,j], [2017-01-01 00:19:30,i]]|
    |2017-01-01 00:20:00|b    |[[2017-01-01 00:17:30,h], [2017-01-01 00:23:30,j], [2017-01-01 00:19:30,i]]|
    |2017-01-01 00:32:00|c    |[[2017-01-01 00:30:30,k], [2017-01-01 00:36:30,l]]                         |
    |2017-01-01 00:44:00|d    |[[2017-01-01 00:44:30,m]]                                                  |
    |2017-01-01 01:12:00|e    |[[2017-01-01 01:13:30,r]]                                                  |
    +-------------------+-----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```